# Keyframes too hight from each others in graph editor

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I'm trying to make simple character head turn (only 10 keyframes)[image]
When I've opened Graph Editor, I couldn't see my 3 keyframes together. First(1frame) and last(10frame) keys was too high from each other. For making changes, I need to scroll up, and space between 1-3 frames too small and they're too far.

Could you help me please?(

Comment: Use the Ctrl key with the MMB held down over the Graph Editor and move it up or down to increase or decrease the scale and left or right to change the horizontal scale. Hit the Home key to get the whole graph in the window

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped!!))

Comment: You're welcome. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#navigation) is the navigation section for the Graph Editor in the Blender manual.